# Young GC becoming very frequent

Tags: apache, tomcat, jvm

OS : Window 7
Tomcat : 8.0 (set memory 2Gb)
Java : 1.8

I've got a Java webapp running on two tomcat instance. 
one is offer very light service.
and the other one is running 3~4 Spring service and, 15~17 simple html web service.

it's normally cpu useage around 15~20%. but now 50~60% used.

I did not touch anything recent 2~3 weeks.

One day, suddenly facing the blue screen!!!

here is screenshot.

[Visual VM - Visual GC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GBZn.png)

Young GC becoming very frequently and S0, S1 Eden, Metaspace, old space 
size getting smaller.

here is more screenshots

[Visual VM Monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBfK5.png)

please help me ...

Comment: I would look at your memory usage by taking a heap dump. A memory leak is a common cause of increasing resource use over time.

Comment: Heavy eden activity is not in itself a problem. The threads that are busy are doing network IO. In particular, the busyness of RMI threads should be investigated. It perhaps suggests that large data transfers are occurring, and those may be putting some memory pressure on the Eden.